# "Reverse" map of `inverse` in torch.unique?

Tags: python, algorithm, pytorch, cuda

I want to implement a function like "reverse" map of `inverse` value of `torch.unique`.

For example, `torch.unique` function can return the unique values `uniques` of long type input `x` and a inverse tensor  that is a mapping from `uniques` to `x`.

```
x = torch.LongTensor([9, 10, 9, 9, 10, 9])
uniques, inverse, counts = torch.unique(x, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
# uniques = [9, 10]
# inverse = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] 
# counts = [4, 2]
print((uniques[inverse] == x).all())  # True
```

For my question, is there some efficient way to get "reverse" inverse `back_map` that mapping from `x` to `uniques`?

```
def reverse_unique(x): ...

uniques, inverse, counts, back_map = reverse_unique(x)
# uniques = [9, 10]
# inverse = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] 
# counts = [4, 2]
# back_map = [0, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4]
print((x[back_map] == uniques.repeat_interleave(counts)).all()) # True
```

In above code, the `back_map` maps the values of  `inverse` to the position of the input `x`.

I know it not a difficult thing implements this function with python loop, but in my case where the input `x` size can reach e8, so the time overhead is intolerable.

So, Is there any high level implementation using pytorch api or the cuda kernel(I tried to use cuda extension to parallelize it but my cuad kernel is slow extremely :sob:)?

```
__global__ void unique_back_map_kernel(
    int32_t num_uni,
    int32_t num_x,
    int64_t* __restrict__ uniques,
    int64_t* __restrict__ cumsum_counts,
    int64_t* __restrict__ x,
    int64_t* __restrict__ out) {
  int32_t n = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (n >= num_uni) {
    return;
  }

  size_t counts = 0;
  auto idx = __ldg(&cumsum_counts[n]);

#pragma unroll
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < num_x; ++i) {
    if (x[i] == uniques[n]) {
      out[idx + counts] = i;
      counts++;
    }
  }
}

std::tuple<at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor> reverse_unique(at::Tensor x) {
  TORCH_CHECK(x.dtype() == at::kLong && x.device().is_cuda());
  auto [uniques, inverse, counts] = at::_unique2(x, false, true, true);
  counts.cumsum_(0);
  // python: cumsum_counts = torch.cat([torch.tensor([0]), cumsum_counts[:-1]])
  auto cumsum_counts = at::cat({at::zeros({1}, counts.options()), counts.slice(0, 0, -1)});

  auto back_map = at::empty_like(x);

  int32_t threads = (uniques.numel() > 256) ? 256 : 32;
  int32_t blocks = (uniques.numel() + threads - 1) / threads;
  unique_back_map_kernel<<<blocks, threads, 0, c10::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream()>>>(
      uniques.numel(),
      x.numel(),
      uniques.data_ptr<int64_t>(),
      cumsum_counts.data_ptr<int64_t>(),
      x.data_ptr<int64_t>(),
      back_map.data_ptr<int64_t>());

  return std::make_tuple(uniques, inverse, cumsum_counts, back_map);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@alexey-birukov probably means this:

If you read the documentation for [`torch.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) you will learn, that it basically just sorts the values and then does a [`torch.unique_consecutive`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique_consecutive.html):

> Currently in the CUDA implementation and the CPU implementation when dim is specified, *torch.unique* always sort [sic] the tensor at the beginning regardless of the *sort* argument. Sorting could be slow, so if your input tensor is already sorted, it is recommended to use `torch.unique_consecutive()` which avoids the sorting.

Another look at the documentation of [`torch.sort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html) lets you know that it will not only return the sorted values but also the permutation of indices for getting back the original order. This permutation seems to be exactly what you are after.

```py
x = torch.LongTensor([9, 10, 9, 9, 10, 9])
sorted, back_map = torch.sort(x)
uniques, inverse, counts = torch.unique_consecutive(sorted, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: Great！This is what I want. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah! For the record, I'm not a lazy ass, just a minimalist.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov Whatever floats your boat, but to quote [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.". The character restriction is there for a reason. A single-line, code-only answer should just be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov And arguably the minimalist answer should have at least been `_, back_map = x.sort()` :P

Comment: Oh. I blame Jupyter Lab make me too relaxed.

Answer (score -1):

```
x.sort()   # blah blah blah (Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 8.)
```

Comment: Great！This is what I want. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!